# Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winapi, service

I am trying to launch an interactive process from Windows Service.
As you know, that's tricky in Windows 7, because services run in another session, but I know it's possible:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx

```
        IntPtr hToken2 = IntPtr.Zero;
       //   WTSQueryUserToken(WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), out userToken);
        WTSQueryUserToken(1, out userToken);
```

userToken is 0. If i hardcode sessionId with 1 , then userToken is not 0, but the process doesn't start(the service doesn't throw any error)

```
        IntPtr newToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES tokenAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        tokenAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tokenAttributes);
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        threadAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(threadAttributes);
       if (!DuplicateTokenEx(userToken, 0x10000000, ref tokenAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
            TOKEN_TYPE.TokenImpersonation, out newToken))
        {
            throw new Exception("ERROR: DuplicateTokenEx returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tokPrivs = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
        tokPrivs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        LUID seDebugNameValue = new LUID();
        if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_DEBUG_NAME, out seDebugNameValue))
        {
            throw new Exception("ERROR: LookupPrivilegeValue returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        tokPrivs.Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1];
        tokPrivs.Privileges[0].Luid = seDebugNameValue;
        tokPrivs.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

        if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(newToken, false, ref tokPrivs, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            throw new Exception("ERROR: AdjustTokenPrivileges returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);

       // si.lpDesktop = "Winsta0\\Winlogon";
        si.lpDesktop = string.Empty;
        if (!CreateProcessAsUser(newToken, "calc.exe", null, ref tokenAttributes, ref threadAttributes,
            true, (int)CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | (int)CreateProcessFlags.INHERIT_CALLER_PRIORITY, IntPtr.Zero,
            "C:\\Windows\\System32", ref si, out pi))
        {
            throw new Exception ("ERROR: CreateProcessAsUser returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
```

my service doesn't start any process. if I use createprocess it launches the process, but it's not on interactive desktop.

edit:

I managed to launch interactive programs with this code. I modified the lpDesktop to string.empty.

Now the problem that remains:
 -how to launch it on winlogon? or even better...on System account.
when I launch the program on the Session 0(where the service is located) the program runs on system account(kind of obvious) but when runs on session 1 it runs on user account.

Comment: Pretty unclear why you decided to hard-code the session number instead of using WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId().  And skip required error checking.  And not document your pinvoke declarations.  These kind of lazy shortcuts of course produce undiagnosable problems and unanswerable questions.

Comment: If you want to launch the new process in the same security context as the service (i.e., SYSTEM) then you shouldn't use WTSQueryUserToken.  Instead, duplicate your own token and use SetTokenInformation to change the session ID.  Note that launching a high-privilege process in an interactive session is a *very* dangerous idea.